# Live Wallpaper not showing up properly android

Tags: android, wallpaper

I have a live wallpaper and an activity that starts it. My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bdcorps.Striped">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <application
        android:label="B! Lite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
      <!--   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" -->

         <activity android:name="com.bdcorps.Striped.StarterActivity"
                  android:label="Striped! Lite"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:label="B! Lite"
            android:name="com.bdcorps.Striped.StripedMain"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/striped"/>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/striped_settings"
            android:name="com.bdcorps.Striped.StripedMainSettings"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".EMAIL"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.bdcorps.Striped.EMAIL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

          </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now the icon - "ic_launcher" only appears in the launcher. In other places such as live wallpaper picker, the icon is grey with "B!" written inside it(I think this is the default).

I have completely uninstalled the app and also cleaned my project but nothing is working.........

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail image and wallpaper short description (which is optional and not used since Honeycomb) should be set in xml/striped, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:settingsActivity="com.bdcorps.Striped.StripedMainSettings"
    android:thumbnail="@drawable/thumbnail"
    android:description="@string/wp_description"
/>
```

The thumbnail image size seems to vary greatly by device, so I just make a single high-resolution jpg and put it in `drawable-nodpi`.

Comment: My problem is half solved as the icon in list changed but the icon in "Application Manager" is not the one I provided, its the default one. Any help?

Comment: You mean it looks like the white paper with a green android on it?

Comment: You could try adding the `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` line again inside the <service> tags.